# How to add a title/label for a group of <LI>'s and shade them?

Tags: css, html-lists

I maintain a page with nearly 100 list items that are constantly changing (items being added and removed).  I'd like to group some of the list items together by shading them and having a label before them.  An ideal solution would include:

1. The shading includes the bullet area
2. LI text is indented as normal (e.g., no list-style-inside)
3. Valid code
4. Easy to update (i.e., don't have to manually update all START attributes when items are added or removed)
5. Doesn't require Javascript

I don't think I can have all of these.

The following code works, but I either have to painstakingly update the "start" attribute in all the different 's, or else I have to use Javascript to number everything.

```css
    ol {margin:0px}

    ol+p {background:silver; margin:0px; padding-left:5px; border-radius:9px 9px 0px 0px; }

    p+ol {background:gainsboro}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ol>

<p>Group</p>
<ol start=3>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
</ol>

<ol start=5>
<li>item 5
<li>item 6
</ol>
```

Comment: Add a class name and style it instead of the start attribute. Then you can play with pseudo-elements to add label

Comment: I don't see how that's an improvement over my original code.  Could you post a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.group::before {
  content: "Group";
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -1em;
  width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  height: 1.5em;
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.group::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: -1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1.5em);
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>

  <div class="group">
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
  </div>

  <li>item 5
  <li>item 6
</ol>
```

I don't know how semantically correct it is but this gets the job done it seems.

Comment: Thank you.  This almost works, but it doesn't include the label.  I tried to modify the code with ::before, applied to the LI for item 4, but the label appears on the same line as item 4 (double-printing on that line).

Comment: Try Adding `position: relative;` to the LI. So the `::before` element stays inside the LI.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to understand exactly what you want. Can u please rephrase?

Comment: I can't be clearer.  I want it to look as in my original post, while meeting the criteria specified in my original post.  None of the suggestions offered look like the result in my original post.

Comment: I made an edit to the original answer. Is it better?

Comment: While this doesn't meet the criterion of valid code (DIV is not allowed as an element of OL), and it's far more code than necessary, it at least keeps the items numbered automatically, so I'll Accept it as a solution.  The secret sauce is that LI's can be wrapped in a DIV, but not a P, because even if we close the P after the LI, the browser will automatically close the P *before* the LI.

Comment: Wow thanks for sharing I didn't know that! @MichaelBluejay

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi: If you're talking about how the P auto-closes but the DIV doesn't, I didn't know that either, until I was tinkering with your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
     ol {
   margin: 0px
 }


 ol>li {
   position: relative;
 }

 ol>li.new-class:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: yellow;
   z-index: -1;
   left: -22px;
 }

 ol>li.new-class:after {
   content: "new";
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: yellow;
   padding: 0px 5px;
 }
```

```html
  <ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li class="new-class">item 5
    <li class="new-class">item 6
  </ol>
```

Without changing your styles and code structure. Add the two rules additional. See is this what you are looking for.

Comment: It's clever, but I'm afraid this doesn't meet criterion #4.  It requires manually updating all the "start" attributes throughout the page when items are added or removed.

Comment: You just have to add the `new-class` to the element when adding. I can't think of an other way to find out the newly added one? start attribute is not needed to add a shading or a label. I just have kept it since it was there in your original code.

Comment: Edited the original answer. See if it helps now.

Comment: This seems far from what I asked about.  I don't know why you're identifying new items as new, that was not one of my criterion.  And your code doesn't completely shade any of the items, nor does it have a title/label line, which *were* my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Serversh's answer, this does the same thing but with far simpler CSS code.  Note, it doesn't meet the criterion of "Valid code", since it's not valid to have DIV as an element of OL, but at least it allows for automatic LI numbering.  Note also that DIV works but not P, because even if we close the P after the LI, the browser will automatically close the P *before* the LI.

```css
/* THE LABEL LINE */

div span {
  display:block;
  margin-left:-5px;
  padding-left:7px;
  background:silver;
  border-radius:9px 9px 0px 0px;
  font-weight:bold;
}


/* THE LI's */

div {
  margin:6px 0px 6px -20px;
  padding-left:5px;
  background:gainsboro;
  border-radius:9px 9px 0px 0px
}

div li {margin-left:20px}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>

<div><span>Group</span>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
</div>

<li>item 5
<li>item 6
</ol>
```